# How to create framework using Selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to create framework using selenium web driver. From where I can start.?? I would like to do like following :

1 - Create simple GUI where our tester team can login to access selenium framework.

2 - I have created lots of selenium programs like test for login , register , forgot password and a lot more. So I want to put one text box to enter site URL and one dropdown to select function which tester want to test in framework GUI.

3 - Tester will enter site URL and will select function he want to test from dropdown like login.

4 - After selection tester will click on button called "Test" and it will run selenium program of Login test automatically.

My Aim to make this framework GUI for fresh tester who do not have much knowledge of selenium and java. So I want to give them everything ready made to test easily.

**I do not need someone who write code for me to build above things. I just want someone who just give me direction and useful links which help me how can I start to create framework.**

Comment: Why it is on HOLD? I already mentioned that I do not need code. I need proper guide to start it. And if you people are saying that it is too broad then for me that is confusing reason. I have to explain with example in question so people get idea what I want and can help me. Also I have often noticed that if we ask question with little detail at that time also you close/discard question and says like not provided enough detail. So whats solution to here ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can easily be achieved using a Continuous Integration tool such as Jenkins or Bamboo
You create various Projects/Plans for each Functionality and a User can trigger test from the CI GUI interface without interfering with the actual Code.

Alternatively it'll be to Create a Java WebApp or a JApplet App that Takes user Input inform of a GUI and Pushes the parameters down to your application logic unit where test if triggered in background.(Working on something similar with a different Framework created a Web interface and pointed the server to an iframe, something like that. )